# How can Lambda authorize website users without using AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization

We are developing an online course website. 
Each course has audio and text (no video). 
Course audio files are stored in S3 and delivered via CloudFront.

There is a fixed low price per course, 
so users can only access the course audio files **after they logged in AND purchase it**.

We already implemented sign-up, log in, user activation email functionality etc.

Every time an authorized user wants to play an audio file,  
browser sends a request to CDN to deliver that audio file.

The problem is this: 
Once CDN delivers the audio file to an authorized user, 
that user can right click on our site audio player, select "inspect', 
copy paste the CDN URL, share the URL on social media, 
and anyone else can listen to that audio file

So we want to add Lambda@edge function, 
that checks every incoming request to see if the user who 
generated this request is really authorized. 
If Lambda authorized, CDN will deliver the audio file. 
If Lambda declines, CDN will deliver an "Authorization Error".

**-1-** 
We don`t want to use AWS Cognito with JWT because 
integrating this service means we will need 
to throw out all our sign-up / log-in related code and 
re-implement this whole logic with Cognito.

**-2-** 
Adding AWS WAF and configure it to accept only requests coming from our site 
by checking HTTP Refer header is not secured and can be easily hacked.

**So how can a Lambda@Edge function accept only requests coming from our site authorized users and decline all requests coming from other users who got their hands on the audio file CDN link?**

**Can Lambda communicate directly to our site database, ask us if user is authorized, and based on our response, authorize/decline the audio file request?**

**Is there any simple tokenization technique between our site and Lambda than can be used?**

Comment: How do you currently actually log a user in? What kind of identification / token does the user provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I'm currently implementing Lamba Authorizers is we have an on-prem Security API which issues a JWT.

So the authorizer valides the JWT with the signing key and ensures it hasn't expired etc.. That authenticates the user so I know who the user is. I then have the authorizer call back to the on-prem security API to return claims.

To do this, your authorizer needs to be attached to a VPC, to a private subnet that has connectivity back to your on-prem environment.

I wasn't able to fully understand how your current system is handling authentication, perhaps in a cookie? Either way, the custom Authorizer can either use token based, so you pass in a bearer token JWT, or you can do it with a request parameter.

From AWS docs:
A request parameter-based Lambda authorizer (also called a REQUEST authorizer) receives the caller's identity in a combination of headers, query string parameters, stageVariables, and $context variables.

So if you don't want to use Cognito, which I'm not using either, or JWT, the only other option I can see here is request parameters.